# How to apply list-view to detail view animation like play store in android?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have an list view in my android application and by taping on any list item, its opens detail screen for tapped item. Now I just want to apply an animation on this event like applied in `Google Play` an app icon is moving to detail view from list item shown in this [Reference Video](https://youtu.be/G6rUYfc33JQ)

please suggest me any good tutorial or example for this.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you find a solution? I would like to achieve the same in android like in Hotel Tonight app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1d-ptlOPOCs (ios video)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are talking about is **Shared Element Activity Transition**, this is new lollipop android translation animation, you can see below link for help

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-new-lollipop-activity-transitions--cms-23711

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

**For Kotlin :**

https://github.com/UttamPanchasara/Shared-Element-Transition-Kotlin

Comment: Thank you Mohit, it helped me

Comment: Welcome,  it's my pleasure to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple now

Set following code on Icon On Click:

```
_view.setTransitionName(_transitionName);
android.app.ActivityOptions optionsCompat =android.app.ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, _view, _transitionName); startActivity(_intent,optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

Set following code to Detail view activity On Create:

```
 _view.setTransitionName(_transitionName);
```

_view = Your view name that you need the transition effect need to apply

_transitionName = any name you want to identify the transition

_intent = The intent used to switch activity