# How to create horizontal Animated recyclerview like google play store ? Not common horizontal recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

When a user will scroll Recyclerview from right to left at the same time the first view will disappear with fade-out animation according to scrolling and background view also be parallax like google play store app.

It will animated recylerview, "not the normal horizontal recyclerview". You can see this in google play, not every time, it appears occasionally

[image: Screenshot from Google Play Store]

Comment: What have you tried to implement this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Comment: User ViewPager2  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2 
with ListAdapter https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter
and set orientation HORIZONATL.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Thanks for your answer but this is not my solution. I want to make recyclerview like google play store animated recylerview, "not the normal horizontal recyclerview". You can see this in google play, not every time, it appears occasionally.

Comment: That first item is most probably not a recyclerview item. Just animate it down when recyclerview is scrolled to the left. Have you tried anything yet? @MehediHasan

Answer (score 3):

According to what you have written, you basically wanted a horizontal recycler view which when scrolled has a fade animation to the header.

I had encountered the same problem and I solved it the following was. I used kotlin, during my development.

Firstly you need to add a scroll listener to your recycler view, i have made an extension function for scroll

```
inline fun RecyclerView.scroll(
        crossinline onScrolled: (RecyclerView, Int, Int) -> Unit = { it, dx, dy -> },
        crossinline onScrolledChanged: (RecyclerView, Int) -> Unit = { it, newState -> }
) {
    addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            onScrolledChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        }
    })
}
```

Now create a divider item decorator for adding the padding to the first item

```
class DividerDecorator(val paddingStart: Float) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
            outRect.left = paddingStart.toInt()
        }
        val lp = view.layoutParams as StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
        val spanIndex = lp.spanIndex
        if (position >= 0) {
                if(spanIndex==0) {
                    outRect.top = 13.px
                    outRect.bottom = 5.px
                }else{
                    outRect.top = 5.px
                    outRect.bottom = 13.px
                }



        }

    }
}
```

Now in your XML place add the image that you want as background and place the recycler view on top of that image.

Once you have done that you just need to add scroll extension to your recyclerview

```
 private var overallScroll = 0;

  recycler.scroll(onScrolled = { _, dx, _ ->
                    overallScroll += dx
                    backgroundView.animate()
                            .alpha(overallScroll.remap(padding))
                            .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start()
                })
```

remap function i have maded to calculate the proper alpha corresponding to scroll displacement.

```
fun Int.remap(offset:Float):Float{
    return 1-(this/offset)
}
```

and yes don't forget to make the recycler view horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RecyclerView with following layout manager

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not my solution. I want to make recyclerview like google play store animated recylerview, not the normal horizontal recyclerview. You can see this in google play not every time, it's appears occasionally.

Comment: Play store App screen is a collection of many RecyclerViews added horizontally or vertically inside a Nested ScrollView as per requirement. If you want you can add animations to Recyclerview refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306779/how-to-apply-list-view-to-detail-view-animation-like-play-store-in-android/35306972